# sliding window threshold count over time axis of gridded datra

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have monthly gridded precipitation data of time lat and lon (324,72,144) and I want to calculate the number of the a certain threshold is exceed in a 60 months sliding window. Asuming threshold is 5 for 1-60 count the number of months below 5 and 2-61, 3-63 and so on.

I have created a for loop to do so yet its seems not to be working as it brings out only empty list after running and I would be glad to have suggestions as to how to handle this.

```
a = []
for i in range(len(lon)):
    for j in range(len(lat)):
        aa = AS[:,j,i].where(AS[:,j,i]<-50).rolling(time=60).count()
```

I am hoping to get aa to be aa.shape = 324,72,144 with frequency counts.
Any suggestions about a better way to create this slinding window loop will be much appreciated.

Comment: The business side is not interesting. Omit it if possible

Comment: Did you mean to have _two_ different variables `a` and `aa`? If not, did you mean to append `aa` to `a`? (You did not.)

Comment: What is the data type of `AS`? It does not look like a numpy array.

Comment: sorry a should be aa instead is my mistake whiles writing the code here  and also AS is xarray data but I could also convert it to numpy array if need be. thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and the output that you would expect for that particular data set?

Comment: @thomas <xarray.DataArray 'precip' (time: 324, lat: 72, lon: 144)>
the data is in netcdf file but basically this is a gridded time series of precipitation data anomalies I could send it to you by email as I dont know how to do it here.